# Random Generator, seed not working

Tags: c++, random

I want to create a class that will return a random number whenever I call it. But when I put it into a loop it returns the same random number each time. I am seeding it once but it still returns the same one over and over again. Its only when I close out of the program and open it again itll be different. Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT

When I cant see how I am calling it every time.

```
  RadomGenerator rg = new...
for(int i =0; i<10; i++){
     rg.createRandomNumber(1,5);}
```

Is this not instansiating the seed only once then calling the method createRandomNumber several times?

```
 RandomGenerator::RandomGenerator()
{
seed = time(0);
}

int RandomGenerator::createRandomNumber(int start, int end)
{

std::function<int()> randomNumber = std::bind(std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(start,end),
                                      mt19937(seed));
qDebug()<< "result" << randomNumber() ;
return randomNumber();

}
```

Comment: You're seeding it every time.

Comment: I am sure there are dozens of duplicates. If you use a seed that changes every second, then you will get a different sequence every new second.

Answer (score 5):

You're seeding it every single time.

```
#include <random>

struct RandomGenerator {
    std::mt19937 _engine;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> _dist;

    RandomGenerator(int start, int end) 
        : _engine { std::random_device{} () },
          _dist(start, end)
    {
    }

    int createRandomNumber()
    {
        return _dist(_engine);
    }

};
```

Note that it's actually not useful to create an instance of `uniform_*_distribution` for a single call either.

Let alone, wrapping that in a `function<>`.

You can usually use a

```
auto mygen = bind(, );
```

Instead of that whole class, and use it:

```
int this_is_random = mygen();
```

In C++14:

```
auto mygen = [ _engine = mt19937{ random_device{}() }, _dist = uniform_int_distribution<>(12, 42) ]() mutable {
    return _dist(_engine);
};
```

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d1319247cb8c053c)</kbd>**

Comment: Good news: there's proposal for a more straightforward `rand()` replacement in c++17 or a TS. So we might even get something of Java quality there :)

Comment: I am trying to implement this in Qt using a header file, but Im not sure how to declare the strut or how it affects the constructer?

Comment: I have included this is a struct in the class but it still doesnt work 

When I call it

  RandomGenerator * ranGen = new RandomGenerator(1,3);
and put the createRandomNumber in a for loop it still prints out the same number multiple times

Comment: I'm not surprised, @hat_to_the_back. Why don't you look at how you're supposed to use this? The whole idea is to /keep/ the same instance. For one thing, there's likely no need to use `new` (rule of thumb: don't use `new` in C++. It's not Java or C#). Next, each time you create the `RandomGenerator` object, you -obviously- seed it again. That's the same error you made in your original code. Feel free to show the actual code you use, or compare for yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is this not instansiating the seed only once then calling the method createRandomNumber several times?

No. In this line you instantiate a `mt19937` each time with the same `seed`:

```
std::function<int()> randomNumber = std::bind(std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(start,end),
                                  mt19937(seed));
```